# How to query mysql to filter data based on certain values?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to do a query on a MySQL database to get data from a column based on certain values. For example, it will display data with the condition of the City column value being 'Paris' or 'London'. Hope someone can help me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE city in ('Paris', 'London');
```

Source: https://www.sqlshack.com/learn-mysql-sorting-and-filtering-data-in-a-table/